# Loading two different json with same store

Tags: json, url, extjs4

Is there a way to load different json files on demand(click), somehow changing the URL. Same store, same model, just changing the url and load().

```
Ext.define('app.gridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'name', 'email', 'phone'
    ]
});

var myStore =Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'app.gridStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'app/kontaktGrid.json',
        reader:{ 
            type:'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }


});

buttons: [{
   text: 'Load1',
   handler:function(){

   myStore.load().url('app/kontaktGrid1.json');

   }
   },{
   text: 'Load2',
   handler:function(){

   myStore.load('app/kontaktGrid2.json');--
```

returning POST  405 Method not allowed

```
   }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both `myStore.load().url('app/kontaktGrid1.json');` or `myStore.load('app/kontaktGrid2.json');` do not update the store URL for retriving data.

In order update the url, you need to do the following:

```
myStore.getProxy().url = "/new-url";
myStore.load();
```

The first statement modifies the store's proxy url. The `load()` which is then called, loads the new data to the store.

Comment: rulez! Thank you so much, two out of two... ;-)

Comment: can you just tell me how to send this data to my grid? Please!

Comment: @Ingol, loading the store should take care of that

Comment: @Abdel-Can you take a look on my post:-----(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139215/json-data-not-showing-when-grid-in-dynamic-tab)----- , mi grid is not showing data when created in tab panel? I did as you told me, but only loading not showing??? :-(